# When is a convolution equal to a product?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, convolution

When is a convolution of two functions equal to their product, i.e. when is $f(t) \star g(t) \equiv \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}\tau f(\tau) g(t-\tau)=f(t) g(t)$ ?

Or equivalently, when is a Fourier transform of a product equal to the product of the relevant Fourier transforms,
$\mathcal{F}[h(\omega) k(\omega)]=\mathcal{F}[h(\omega)] \mathcal{F}[k(\omega)]$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Comment: Interesting question; please define convolution for your setting. Usually, it's an integral of some sort: over what interval are you integrating?

Answer (score 6):

Let $\omega=\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\mathrm{i}$, and let $\bar{\omega}$ be the complex conjugate of $\omega$. Let
$$\begin{align}
f(t)&=\mathrm{e}^{-\pi \omega t^2}\\
g(t)&=\mathrm{e}^{-\pi \bar{\omega} t^2}\text{.}
\end{align}$$

Then from
$$\begin{align}
\omega+\bar{\omega}&=1\\
\omega\bar{\omega}&=1
\end{align}$$
we get
$$\begin{align}
f(t)g(t)&=\mathrm{e}^{-\pi t^2}\\
(f\star g)(t)&=\mathrm{e}^{-\pi t^2}\text{.}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Very nice. It's interesting, though, that neither of our examples use smooth real-valued functions. (Mine uses a distribution, whereas yours goes to the complex plane.)

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $f(t)=1$ and $g(t)=\delta(t)$. Then$$(f\ast g)(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty (1)\delta(t-\tau)\,d\tau=\delta(t)=(1)\delta(t)=f(t)g(t)$$ as was desired. Additionally, note that their Fourier transforms are $$\mathcal{F}[f](\omega)=\delta(\omega),\qquad \mathcal{F}[g](\omega)=1$$
(up to an overall multiplicative constant depending on your convention for the FT). So the Fourier transform just swaps which function is the constant function and which is the delta function.

Comment: An obvious question is whether these are the only such examples. At some level they're not: for instance, one could use $f(t)=2$ or $g(t)=\delta(t-\tau)$ without breaking the result. However, it seems entirely possible that the only such pairs possible are constant functions with delta functions.

Comment: Very promising is a convolution of two Gaussians. The result is also a Gaussian, and it is even possible to equate the factors at $x^2$. Unfortunately, they are still not identical but just proportional.