# Find all functions whose convolution is the same as their square.

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, convolution

Find all functions who's self-convolution is the same as their square.

To make it explicit, find all $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t - \tau)f(\tau) d\tau = (f(t))^2
$$

Or the same problem on a limited domain $f:(-a,a) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$$
\int_{-a}^{a} f(t - \tau)f(\tau) d\tau = (f(t))^2
$$

Edit:
Anne Bauval has asked for a motivation for this problem.  If you consider any non-linear ODE in 1D with derivatives beyond the first, there are no simple methods of solution.  For example:

$$x''' + (x'')^2 + x^2 x' = 0$$

The fourier transform of these types of problems become polynomials of multiplication and convolution for example:
$$(i\omega)^3\hat{x}(\omega) + [(i\omega)^2\hat{x}(\omega)] * [(i\omega)^2\hat{x}(\omega)] + [(i\omega)\hat{x}(\omega)] * \hat{x}(\omega) * \hat{x}(\omega) = 0$$

The above example is the simplest polynomial using multiplication and convolution. So, solving this problem would be a first step towards solving more complex convolution and multiplication polynomials. At some point, this method could allow you to solve previously unsolvable non-linear ODEs.

Bruno B.: Pointed out a related, but not identical question math.stackexchange.com/q/3336615/1104384

Comment: Of course, a proof that no solutions exist would also be satisfactory.

Comment: I personnaly find it a puzzling hence interesting question, but according to the rules of this site, it is threatened of deletion if you do not edit it to include some motivations and   more thoughts than "I have no idea". [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: In the specific case of $a = \frac{1}{2}$, $f \equiv \pm 1$ are solutions, so there is hope that there are still solutions for other limited domains or for $\mathbb{R}$ maybe.

Comment: There was a related question about more generally when convolutions are equal to products, however there was no progress towards finding a classification it seems: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3336615/1104384

Comment: An analogous discrete problem would be: find sequences $a_n$ so that $$\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n\right)^2 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n^2 x^n$$

Comment: This problem can be expressed in terms of Fourier transforms as $\left(\mathcal{F}_t[f(t)](\omega)\right){}^2=\mathcal{F}_t\left[f(t)^2\right](\omega)$.

Comment: Steven Clark, yes that had occurred to me, but I couldn't see a way forward from there.

Comment: FWIW: If $\hat f= \lambda f$ is an eigenfunction of the Fourier transform then  by the Product Rule for convolutions, $(f*f) \hat{}= (\hat f)^2=\lambda^2 f^2$. This is close, but not literally equal, to the identity you desire. However the fact that $|\lambda |\ne 1$ may provide an obstruction to solvability of your problem.

Comment: For the full $\mathbb R$ case, if $g(x) = f(kx)$, then $[g*g](x) = k^{-1}[f*f](k x)$. So if $f$ satisfies $f*f = k f^2$, then $g(x) = f(k x)$ will satisfy $g*g = g^2$. So it is sufficient to find $f*f\propto f^2$ in the full $\mathbb R$ case.